# Microservices with spring integration and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, microservices

I'm a bit new with microservices (and SI) and want to make a POC following a microservices architecture style. I've seen that I can use Spring Boot for deployment and SI for the development but found little docs about how to combine them (just an example in Spring Boot home page). Do you know about best practices or recommendations on how to combine this two technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no anything specific on the matter.

Spring Boot utilizes `IntegrationAutoConfiguration` to switch on `@EnableIntegration` and with that you can go ahead with best from both worlds: Boot stuff to inject, e.g. `AmqpTemplate`, `MongoTemplate`, `DataSource` etc. to the Spring Integration configs or use from SI XML components definitions.

See our samples on the matter which is based on the Spring Boot:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/dsl
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/web-sockets
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/stomp-chat

Comment: Gary, Artem, thank you  very much! I'll check this samples and probably write you for more doubts.

Answer (score 1):

A number of the [sample apps](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) including those under `dsl` and the `stomp-chat` app are Spring Boot/Spring Integration apps.